# convert UTF 8 string codes(codes are holded in string variable) into UTF 16 string(actual utf 16 chars)

Tags: javascript, java, utf-8, type-conversion, utf-16

I have converted UTF 16 to UTF 8 (method used : toUTF8Array)codes in javascript and sent the code from ajax call(note : UTF 16 chars is ugly and it needed encoding which I dont want!)
Js code :

```
var compressed = LZString.compressToUTF16(uncompressed64Data);
var utf8values = toUTF8Array(compressed); 
    jQuery.ajax({
data :"img=+" utf8values 
}
```

I have received the UTF 8 codes in java server side as follow :

```
 String utf8values = request.getParameter("img");
```

fyi, outcome of sop:
utf8values : 225,186,162,227,160,181,229,160,165

Now I want change the codes into actual UTF 16 string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `"225,186,162,227,160,181,229,160,165"` The actual string you have?

Comment: Yes . This is sample I given

Comment: So it's supposed to be `Ả㠵堥` ?

Comment: The attribute is named `img`, are you trying to send image data to the backend?

Comment: @Oleg : exactly!!  By the way are we able to send UTF 16 chars (Ả㠵堥) without encoding into server.? currently I have huge UTF16 data which is not going to server due to non encoding!!

Comment: @Kayaman : Yes. I am going reconvert and make image from it

Comment: You need to encode to something, usually base64 is used.

Comment: You really need to send the data as a binary stream, instead of trying to convert it to text (which it isn't) in different encodings.

Comment: @Oleg : I am compressing base64 format, in order to reduce the transfer bandwidth.

Comment: check the length of `uncompressed64Data` and `utf8values` probably you increased it instead of reducing.

Comment: Yes. I know.. I am going to reduce the string which by some algorithm again to reduce the string chars. and the same way I will intercept in server side and conver. It seems I am rounding more but I got reduce the transfer bandwidth size somehow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
String[] split = "225,186,162,227,160,181,229,160,165".split(",");
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(split.length);
Arrays.stream(split).forEach(a -> bb.put((byte)Integer.parseInt(a)));
bb.flip();
String string = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(bb).toString();
```

Comment: excellent answer. I would be more happy if you able to extract this java 1.7. Thanks

Comment: @WillMcavoy I just used it for some brevity replacing `forEach` with a loop is easy enough.